# Making a card slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a website and I wanted to add a card slider. (I am in learning phase). Everything is working fine but when I am on the last slide and I am increasing the media width a white space is showing.(like when I am on the last slide on mobile view and when I am changing it to bigger screen a white space is showing) Idk really is this a problem or not.
[on smaller screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDOEX.png)
 [on larger screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYDrB.png)
html is

```
<div class="container4">
        <h2 class="heading head1">Most Popular Plans</h2>
        <div class="slidesContainer">
          <div class="slider">
            <div class="slide slide1">
              
              <div class="slideImg slideImg1"><div class="price"><p>Rs 20000</p></div></div>
              <div class="slideAbt">
                <div class="abtTrip">
                  <h2><i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>Goa</h2>
                  <p><i class="fa-solid fa-map"></i>5 Days Trip</p>
                </div>
                <div class="knowMore">
                  
                  <button class="knowMoreBtn">KnowMore</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide slide2">
              <div class="slideImg slideImg2"><div class="price"><p>Rs 20000</p></div></div>
              <div class="slideAbt">
                <div class="abtTrip">
                  <h2><i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>Banaras</h2>
                  <p><i class="fa-solid fa-map"></i>5 Days Trip</p>
                </div>
                <div class="knowMore">
                  
                  <button class="knowMoreBtn">KnowMore</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide slide3">
              <div class="slideImg slideImg3"><div class="price"><p>Rs 20000</p></div></div>
              <div class="slideAbt">
                <div class="abtTrip">
                  <h2><i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>Rajasthan</h2>
                  <p><i class="fa-solid fa-map"></i>5 Days Trip</p>
                </div>
                <div class="knowMore">
                  
                  <button class="knowMoreBtn">KnowMore</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide slide4">
              <div class="slideImg slideImg4"><div class="price"><p>Rs 20000</p></div></div>
              <div class="slideAbt">
                <div class="abtTrip">
                  <h2><i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>Idk</h2>
                  <p><i class="fa-solid fa-map"></i>5 Days Trip</p>
                </div>
                <div class="knowMore">
                  
                  <button class="knowMoreBtn">KnowMore</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide slide5">
              <div class="slideImg slideImg5"><div class="price"><p>Rs 20000</p></div></div>
              <div class="slideAbt">
                <div class="abtTrip">
                  <h2><i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>Idk</h2>
                  <p><i class="fa-solid fa-map"></i>5 Days Trip</p>
                </div>
                <div class="knowMore">
                  
                  <button class="knowMoreBtn">KnowMore</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="btnContainer">
            <button class="btn prev">prev</button>
            <button class="btn next">next</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

css is

```
.container4 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: #f5f5ff;
  margin-top: -1.9em;
}

.head1::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background: #f4f02a;
  height: 10px;
  width: 8em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  left: 7px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.head1 {
  margin-top: 1em;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slidesContainer {
  height: 35em;
  max-width: 58em;
  margin: 1em 0;

  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider {
  height: 25em;
  /* background: grey; */
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2.5em 0em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.slide {
  height: 25em;
  min-width: 18em;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.btnContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn {
  margin: 1em;
  border: none;
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #0f0f5b;
  color: #f4f02a;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slideImg {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  height: 75%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.slideImg1 {
  background: url(/img/goaimg.jpg) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.slideImg2 {
  background: url(/img/banimg.jpg) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.slideImg3 {
  background: url(/img/rajimg.jpg) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.slideImg4 {
  background: url(/img/testimg.jpg) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.slideImg5 {
  background: url(/img/testimg.jpg) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.price {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 7em;
  height: 2.5em;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0px 20px;
  background: #0f0f5b;
  color: #f4f02a;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.slideAbt {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #0f0f5b;
  height: 6.25em;
  color: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

.abtTrip {
  margin: 0px 0px 0 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 15px;
}

.fa-solid {
  color: #f6ef2c;
  padding-right: 8px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.knowMore {
  margin: 0px 15px 0px 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 15px;
}

.knowMoreBtn {
  padding: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f6ef2c;
  height: 2.5em;
  width: 7em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 736px) and (max-width: 1100px) {
  .slidesContainer {
    width: 38.9em;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 736px) {
  .slidesContainer {
    width: 19.3em;
  }
}
```

js is

```
const next = document.querySelector(".next");
const prev = document.querySelector(".prev");
const Slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
const Sliders = document.querySelectorAll(".slider");
console.log(Sliders);
let counter = 0;
next.addEventListener("click", function () {
  counter++;
  slide();
});
prev.addEventListener("click", function () {
  counter--;

  slide();
});

function slide() {
  var s = Slides.length;
  var x = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 736px) and (max-width: 1100px)");
  var z = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1100px)");

  if (x.matches) {
    s = s - 1;

    if (counter >= s) {
      counter = 0;
    }
    if (counter === s) {
      counter = 0;
    }
    if (counter < 0) {
      counter = s - 1;
    }
  }
  if (z.matches) {
    s = s - 2;
    if (counter >= s) {
      counter = 0;
    }
    if (counter === s) {
      counter = 0;
    }
    if (counter < 0) {
      counter = 1;
    }
    // console.log(counter);
  }

  if (counter === s) {
    counter = 0;
  }
  if (counter < 0) {
    counter = s - 1;
  }
  console.log(counter);
  Sliders.forEach(function (slider) {
    slider.style.transform = `translateX(-${counter * 309}px)`;
  });
}
```

ik the code is not beautiful and optimized because I am just learning. Please anyone help me. And also help me how can I do it more efficiently.(I know there are libraries like swiper js but I wanted to do it by myself to learn )

I have tried to move individual cards also but the same problem occurs

Comment: I copied/pasted your code to a codepen: https://codepen.io/yunzen/pen/KKrGdmV
I can't see any whitespace. On what system are you testing? Can you add a screenshot with the issue marked?

Comment: on smaller screen go to the last slide and then start increasing your browser or screen size 
you will get the same problem

Comment: I can't manage to reproduce the issue in the codepen either. But seeing how your slider is using flexbox, and the slides only have `min-width: 18em;` set, they will presumably shrink or grow at certain widths - and that then probably doesn't work nicely along that "magic number" you used there in your code, `translateX(-${counter * 309}px)`

Comment: added the image see it 
and I have converted em into px and then used it by trial and error(sad)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).